# Should you format operator<< for classes?

Tags: c++, class, operators, standards

As in, should the operator>> match the operator<< ?

Database Example:

If the operator>> reads in something of the following format:

```
2
Joe 500 20 1
Bob 250 30 0
```

should the operator<< output that? Or something like this:

```
Record: 1/2
Name: Joe
Balance: 500
Transactions: 20
Premium Account: Yes
```

And then have a separate writeFile() function?

I know either would work, but what is the "accepted standard"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have an istream `operator>>` overload for a type that reads data in a particular format, then if you implement an ostream `operator<<` overload for the same type, it should output in the same format (otherwise, it could get quite confusing).

Answer (score 3):

This kind of operator overloading is IMO a big misuse and misconception.
Use overloading where it really makes some sense.

For debug purposes, have `toString()` and override << to call it.
Do not override >> at all.

`>>` and `<<` generally serve for sending serialized data to streams, not for communication with user.

My 2 eurocents.

Comment: I disagree:  if you intend to read or write data from a stream, then overloading the "stream operators" is both straightforward and idiomatic.

Comment: You're right - I was adding that to my answer when you were writing this :)

Answer (score 0):

Both or independent of each other, according to your will you can overload them.

Comment: I think the OP knows that. He's asking whether it's a good idea to do so. For example, you can overload && but in general you should avoid doing so.

Comment: @Billy 
 ya, you are correct. But overriding << is always good for frequent checking(when you are coding).